# Reducing if-else statements in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, refactoring, conditional-statements

I have the following code:

```
void f(String t)
{
  if(t.equals("a"))
  {
    someObject.setType(ObjectType.TYPE_A);
  }
 else if(t.equals("b"))
  {
    someObject.setType(ObjectType.TYPE_B);
  }

// 50 more similar code

}
```

Is there any simple way to rewrite the if-else condition so as not to have that much code?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You should use something to eliminate the repetition of `someObject.setType(ObjectType....))` If `ObjectType` is an `enum`, then write a method there similar to `valueOf` that will achieve that. See if you like this kind of solution:

```
void f(String t) { someObject.setType(ObjectType.byName(t)); }

enum ObjectType {
  TYPE_A, TYPE_B;
  public static ObjectType byName(String name) {
    return valueOf("TYPE_" + name.toUpperCase());
  }
}
```

Comment: Not nit-picking, you just need to be careful with the exception handling here; You have to wrap the return value in a try-catch block, to handle garbage-in scenarios.

Comment: @questzen Well sure, this is just the basic outline. Depending on wish there are various approaches to handling garbage. I personally most often prefer the raw exception (if it is indeed an error to pass in garbage). That gives you the most direct debug info.

Answer (score 15):

Use a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) (which you'll have to populate) that maps from `String` to whatever type your `ObjectType.TYPE_x` values are.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking too. But only doubt I had was memory required to store those strings and the lookup required to get the type. Is there no other way?

Comment: @Asha the strings in the map (because they're interned) will take no more space than the string literals.  The lookup time will be reduced because the map lookup will be `O(log n)` instead of `O(n)`.

Comment: @Alnitak Using a `HashMap` could even get to `O(1)`.

Comment: @Asha If you use an enum, you won't have to manage the map explicitly. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Mudu yup, that would be a good (concrete) implementation to use in this instance.

Answer (score 14):

I would add this as a functionality of the enum:

```
public enum ObjectType {
    TYPE_A("a"),
    TYPE_B("b");

    private String stringType;

    private ObjectType(String stringType) {
        this.stringType = stringType;
    }

    public String getStringType() {
        return this.stringType;
    }

    public static ObjectType fromStringType(String s) {
        for (ObjectType type : ObjectType.values()) {
            if (type.stringType.equals(s)) {
                return type;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No ObjectType with stringType " + s);
    }
}

...

void f(String t) {
    someObject.setType(ObjectType.fromStringType(t));
}
```

Comment: This is the method I usually use. Is better than relying on the constant names because it is more flexible and harder to break.

Answer (score 4):

If you can refactor `t` into a `char`, you could use `switch` instead (Java 6):

```
void f(char t) {

  switch(t) {

    case 'a`:
      someObject.setType(ObjectType.TYPE_A);
      break;
    case 'b':
      someObject.setType(ObjectType.TYPE_B);
      break;

    // ...

  }

}
```

As Marko pointed out, you could go with `String` too in Java 7.

It isn't that much shorter, but more elegant. Moreover, I think it might be faster too, as `switch` works close to `O(1)` with jump tables (Can somebody confirm whether this is true?), whether a number of `if` statements is `O(n)`.

Fore more complex implementations than just a single `setType` you might think of a [State Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternState.aspx) implementation too.

Answer (score 2):

**1.You can go for Switch statement if you have number of if conditions more than 3.**

**2.you can convert your if else statements to [ternary operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#C.2C_Java.2C_JavaScript)**

Answer (score 1):

The other suggestions are great - particularly smarter enums and maps.  But the first most basic refactoring I would tackle here is to extract a method to return the enum directly and have the caller perform nothing more than the setType to that method's return value.

```
void f(String t) {
  final ObjectType type = findType(t);
  if (type != null)
    someObject.setType(type);
  }

ObjectType findType(String t) {
  if (t.equals("a")) return ObjectType.TYPE_A;
  if (t.equals("b")) return ObjectType.TYPE_B;
  // 50 more similar code
  }
```

In some cases this will be sufficient in and of itself; in others the `findType()` method may lead you to a simple map- or enum-based solution.